# Tracking design changes on the site

Tags: angular

How can track changes on the site when the design changes. At the moment, I have to clear the cache in the browser to see the changes I made. Is there any way to give different urls, for example: `example.com/style.css?v=2022080401`. Or something similar?

angular.json:

```
"styles": [
    "node_modules/ngx-toastr/toastr.css",
    "src/assets/styles/style.scss"
],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are not using `outputHashing` parameter in the angular.json. This parameter is responsible to create hash of your file based on the content and append it in file name. So whenever you change the content then hash will be changed.

Set `outputHashing: all` in angular.json. It will generate style.css file with below kind of name.

```
styles.ea8056b9f3388cc13d82.css
```

PS: run command **ng build --prod**. Above parameter is available in `configuration > production`

Comment: but I had it initially  `"ng build --aot --output-hashing=all --prod",` installed and it didn't help.

Comment: This should work as command is correct. I advice you to do all of this configuration in the angular.json file. and only run `ng build --prod`. It will take configuration from the json file.